# SPErrorGizmoInstallNeverFinishedErrorMessage in Watchkit

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I am running a watchkit app which uses app groups and I can't seem to get it running at all. Anytime I try and run the app I get an alert which says  "SPErrorGizmoInstallNeverFinishedErrorMessage".
The code in my glance controller is relatively short.

```
let sharedGroupName = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("Shared Group") as! String

var sharedDefaults:NSUserDefaults!

override func willActivate() {

    super.willActivate()

    sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: sharedGroupName)

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func update() {

    println(sharedDefaults?.valueForKey("timeMessage") as! String)

}
```

The code in my ViewController.swift is short as well also just setting this share defaults object:

```
let sharedGroupName = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("Shared Group") as! String
var sharedDefaults:NSUserDefaults!
sharedDefaults?.setObject(timeMessage.text, forKey: "timeMessage")
sharedDefaults?.synchronize()
```

This error is preventing me from running any watchkit app at all. Not the main app or the glance or notification. 
I have one app group which is listed in the info.plist. 
I have a custom build setting to the app groups name. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This error occurs even when not using any NSUserDefault / Shared-Groups code. Oran's solution worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error I was able to fix this by unplugging my external display from my computer. Whether this was the real issue I don't know. All I know is that when I had the external monitor plugged in I got this error and when I unplugged it the error went away. I tested it several times.

Comment: i am working on laptop no external display and no other solution too work for me

Answer (score 12):

I fixed this issue by going to the simulator's watch companion app, unchecking the installation for the watch app, then turning it back on. Nothing else worked.

Comment: @Nicopuri you open the Apple Watch app on the iPhone simulator, select your watch app from the list, and turn the toggle off and on.  However, that didn't work for me, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28990516/71262

Comment: I wish apple would fix there buggy mess that is Xcode 6. You almost need to do a voodoo dance to get there software to work properly sometimes.

Comment: Deleting the iPhone app (which also removes the watch app) on the Simulator before building also works.

Answer (score 11):

The only thing that worked for me was to Reset Content and Settings in the simulator.  Toggling the watch app off and on in the Apple Watch settings app didn't do it for me.

Answer (score 10):

From reading other Apple Developer forum messages, `SPErrorGizmoInstallNeverFinishedErrorMessage` seems to occur when the Watch App info.plist has an invalid setting.

I was trying different versions of `WKCompanionAppBundleIdentifier` and that was my error. When I deleted the copied line, that worked again.

Comment: It was also the case for my project. I've added 'Application Category' without value, which is first key when you click '+'. So basicly I added something to 'Watch App' Info.plist file by accident and it was whole problem.

Comment: This was the cause of the problem for me as well. I had added an extra key to the Watch App's Info.plist, and removing it fixed things

Comment: I had the same identifier both for the WatchKit App and the WatchKit Extension

Answer (score 5):

This message started appearing when I added custom keys in the info.plist file.

Comment: I accidentally added an extra key to the WatchKit App's Info.plist. Deleting the key fixed the issue.

Comment: i did this accidentally too. after removing the custom keys i had to delete, do a clean und reinstall the app.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was "Targeted Device Family" settings

For parent app, you could keep it iPhone/iPad (or iPhone, up to you);
For watchkitextension, set it to iPhone;
For watchkitapp, if you want to run in the simulator, set it to iPhone. For actually device, the value seems to be 4 (which you cannot set directly from Xcode yet as of 20150416)

Answer (score 1):

I did nothing but restart Simulator & Clean-build app, then it worked again. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the group to share the data with IOS app and your apple watch kit using the NSUserdefault, you can follow these steps:
1. Add the group app id in capabilities part of IOS targets app and  target watch kit
2. when you want to save the data to NSUSerDefault:

```
  var groupData = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.demoShareData")
// note that suiteName is group app id 
//        var str = "demotest"
        groupData?.setObject(newYearLabel.text, forKey: "timeRemaining")
        groupData?.synchronize()
```

3. when you want to take the data from NSuserDefault:

```
 var groupData = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.demoShareData")
        groupData?.synchronize()

        if groupData?.objectForKey("timeRemaining") != nil {
                var str = groupData?.objectForKey("timeRemaining") as String
                    println("str \(str)")
            self.myLabel.setText(str)

        } else {
            println("error")
        }
```

Hope this help :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in Xcode 8.3. Make sure that the build setting "Targeted Device Family" is set to iPhone in the WatchKit extension.

Answer (score 0):

I Deleted the App from the simulator, and reinstalled. Seemed to work.

I tried a couple of the other option.

Answer (score 0):

CMD SHIFT K - clean
CMD RUN - run

the error dissapears!